# How to Execute a Specific Part of a Function

Tags: 6, nodes

I am building a function in a custom module, and I want to be able to execute only a specific part of that function.

I am starting with the [hook_node_api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) to see if an event occurs, and if that event occurs, I want to execute a only a specific part of that custom function.

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {

    case 'presave'
    if (  $node->type == 'property' ){
        $old = node_load($node->nid);
        if($old->field_realtor_reference[0]['uid'] == NULL && $node->field_realtor_reference[0]['uid'] !== NULL){
               mymodule_tn_complete($node);  
        }
      }

      break;
  } 
}  

function mymodule_tn_complete( $node)
{
  //Do something 
  //Do Something Else


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally might reduce some of the conditionals as in some cases they're just checking one item and can basically be placed into the same conditional statement.

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  // Placed the $op and node type checks in the same conditional.
  // There's no particular reason they have to be separated since
  // the rest of the code is dependent upon both being TRUE.
  if ($op == 'presave' && $node->type == 'property') {
    $old = node_load($node->nid);

    if($old->field_usera_ref[0]['uid'] != $node->field_user_ref[0]['uid']){
      // Also, it is not necessary to assign the string to $type. You can
      // just pass the string 'realtor_assign' directly without assigning it.
      // Since your second parameter in the function signature is $type this
      // string will automatically be assigned to it.
      mymodule_tn_complete($node, 'realtor_assign');   
    }

    if($old->field_userb_reference[0]['uid'] != $node->field_userb_ref[0]['uid']){
      mymodule_tn_complete($node, 'am_assign');    
    }

    if($old->field_userc_ref[0]['uid'] != $node->field_userc_ref[0]['uid']){
      mymodule_tn_complete($node, 'trep_assign');   
    } 
  }
}


function mymodule_tn_complete($node, $type) {
  switch($type){ 
    case 'realtor_assign':
      //Do Stuff
      break;

    case 'am_assign':
      //Do other stuff
      break;

    case 'trep_assign':
      // Do different stuff
      break;
  }   
}
```

Other than those personal preferences from experience, I don't really see anything wrong with it in principal. It looks good. This function is not making any database calls so it should not be putting must strain on the performance. Implementing the hook should not do that. Even if you're not implementing the hook other modules undoubtedly are.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading you right you're asking a basic program flow-control question.  In PHP, like most programming languages, you can use flow control statements like `switch` and `if` to only execute certain blocks of code, or move some blocks into separate functions.

Since it's your own function you're calling here it completely up to you how to handle it. As you gain experience you'll learn ways to determine what to separate out into unique functions and what to just use `if` statements to control.

To use an `if` statement, you'll probably need to add a parameter to your function to let you determine which pieces to execute.

Comment: Ya..a little new to php. I added an answer with my code. Can you tell me if it looks right?

Answer (score 0):

Okay - It seems to be working with the code below...can you tell me if this looks okay? Also, is presave heavy on the database resources? The page seems to be running slower now.

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {

case 'presave':
if($node->type == 'property'){
$old = node_load($node->nid);

if($old->field_usera_ref[0]['uid'] != $node->field_user_ref[0]['uid']){
mymodule_tn_complete($node, $type = 'realtor_assign');   
}

if($old->field_userb_reference[0]['uid'] != $node->field_userb_ref[0]['uid']){
mymodule_tn_complete($node, $type = 'am_assign');    
}

if($old->field_userc_ref[0]['uid'] != $node->field_userc_ref[0]['uid']){
mymodule_tn_complete($node, $type ='trep_assign');   
 } 
break;
  } 
 }
}


function mymodule_tn_complete( $node, $type)
{
        switch($type){ 

        case 'realtor_assign':
        //Do Stuff
        break;

        case 'am_assign':
        //Do other stuff
        break;

        case 'trep_assign':
        // Do different stuff
        break;
        }   
}
```